# Insert List into XML File

Tags: c#, xml, linq

**I created an xml file as shown below as well as I have a list of elements that i got using linq query.**

```
    public bool createXMLFile()
            {
                bool myval;
                try
                {
                var xEle = new XElement("Plist");
                string path1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();
                string un = "\\" + GlobalClass.GlobalVar + "empFinance.xml";
                GlobalClass.GlobalUrl = path1 + un;
                xEle.Save(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);
                    Debug.WriteLine("*************************************************************************");
                    Debug.WriteLine("Success! Converted to XML " + GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);
                    myval = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("**********************************************************************");
                    Debug.WriteLine("EmployeeForEmpFinance exception" + ex.Message);
                    myval = false;
                }
                return myval;  
            }
```

---

```
public void BeginPayrollRunProcess(List<EmployeeEmploy> PrepList)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("EmployeeFinance");
        Debug.WriteLine("*****************************************************************");

        var finalList = new List<EmployeeEmploy>();
        var context = new SSPModel.sspEntities();


        foreach (var xEle in PrepList)
        {
           var query = from c in context.Employee_Employ
                        join d in context.Employee_Financial
                        on c.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id equals             d.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id
                        where d.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id == xEle.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id //&& d.Approved_on != null
                        select new EmployeeFinance
                        {
                            Base_Pay = d.Base_Pay,
                            Housing_Allowance = d.Housing_Allowance,
                            Base_Pay_Currency = d.Base_Pay_Currency,
                            Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id = d.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id
                        };
            var empfinance = query.SingleOrDefault();

            if (query.Count() == 1)
            {
                xEle.Housing_Allowance = empfinance.Housing_Allowance.GetValueOrDefault();
                xEle.Base_Pay = empfinance.Base_Pay;
                xEle.Base_Pay_Currency = empfinance.Base_Pay_Currency;
                xEle.Gross_Pay = xEle.Housing_Allowance.GetValueOrDefault() + xEle.Base_Pay; // suppose to get gross pay up to this point
                finalList.Add(xEle);
            }

        }
        Misc_Classes.XMLCreator wer = new Misc_Classes.XMLCreator();
        bool myVal = wer.createXMLFile();

        if (myVal == true)
        {
            insertInitialList(finalList); // method call to insert list into xml file.
        }
        else
        {
            Security.ErrorControl aa = new Security.ErrorControl();
            aa.displayErrorMsg = " Creating XML";
            aa.endRequest(HttpContext.Current, 2);
            Security.ErrorControl.CaptureErrorMessage(0, 0, "my val return false", "BeginPayrollRunProcess", GlobalClass.GlobalVar);
            return;
        }
    }
```

--

```
public void insertInitialList(List<EmployeeEmploy> finalList)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);
            XElement xelement = XElement.Load(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);

            try
            {

                var result = from element in doc.Descendants("Plist")
                             select element;
                foreach (var ele in result)
                {

                    ele.Element("Plist").Add(from emp in finalList
                                                         select new XElement("EmployeeFinance",
                                                                        new XElement("EmployeeEmploy_Id", emp.ID),
                                                                        new XElement("EmpPersonal_Id", emp.Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id),
                                                                        new XElement("Employee_Number", emp.Employee_No),
                                                                        new XElement("Gross_Pay", emp.Gross_Pay),
                                                                        new XElement("Grade_Id", emp.Grade_Id),
                                                                        new XElement("Position_Id", emp.Substantive_designation),
                                                                        new XElement("Basic_Pay", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("Housing", emp.Housing_Allowance.GetValueOrDefault()),
                                                                        new XElement("Base_Pay", emp.Base_Pay),
                                                                        new XElement("PAYE", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("NetPay", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("Sum_AllGrade", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("Sum_AllPosition", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("Allowance-Grade"),
                                                                        new XElement("TotalTaxableAllowance-Grade", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("TotalNonTaxableAllowance-Grade", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("Allowance-Position", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("TotalTaxableAllowance-Position", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("TotalNonTaxableAllowance-Position", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("TotalNonTaxableAllowance"),
                                                                        new XElement("TotalTaxableAllowance"),
                                                                        new XElement("Add_Earnings_NonTaxableTotal", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("Add_Earnings_NonTaxable"),
                                                                        new XElement("Add_Earnings_TaxableTotal", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("Add_Earnings_Taxable"),
                                                                        new XElement("Benefits_TaxableTotal", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("Benefits_Taxable"),
                                                                        new XElement("Benefits_NonTaxableTotal", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("Benefits_NonTaxable"),
                                                                        new XElement("NIS_Gross", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("CHMS"),
                                                                        new XElement("CHMSTotal"),
                                                                        new XElement("PensionEmp", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("PensionEmpr", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("NISEmp", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("NISEmpr", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("TotalNonStatDedct", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("NonStatDedct"),
                                                                        new XElement("TotalDeduction", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("TotalTaxableEarnings", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("TotalNonTaxableEarnings", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("No_DaysWorked", emp.NoDaysWorked),
                                                                        new XElement("Payperiod_EndDate", emp.endDate.ToShortDateString()),
                                                                        new XElement("Exchange_Rate", emp.Exchange_rate),
                                                                        new XElement("Currency", emp.Base_Pay_Currency),
                                                                        new XElement("Date_Appointment", emp.Date_of_Appointment.GetValueOrDefault().ToShortDateString()),
                                                                        new XElement("Date_Employment", emp.Date_of_Employment.ToShortDateString()),
                                                                        new XElement("Date_Termination", emp.Termination_date_actual.GetValueOrDefault().ToShortDateString()),
                                                                        new XElement("Payperiod_StartDate", emp.startDate.ToShortDateString()),
                                                                        new XElement("BatchNumber", emp.BatchNumber),
                                                                        new XElement("PAYE_ToDate_Computed", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("Income_Tax_RateID", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("NIS_RateID", 0),
                                                                        new XElement("NIS_weeks_worked", 0)
                                                                    ));
                     doc.Save(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);
                }



            }
        catch (Exception e){
            Debug.WriteLine("********************************************************");
            Debug.WriteLine("EmployeeForEmpFinance exception" + e.Message);
            }

        }
```

In this last method i am trying to iterate thought my list (finallist) and insert it into my xml file. I am getting an error saying that i need to instantiate the object. I know i am doing something wrong with my method that i am using to insert the list into the xml file. Some ideas are welcome. thank  you

**EDITED

---

in a shorten version of the problem above .. i figure it out and list the code below. thank you**

```
public void insertInitialList(List<EmployeeEmploy> finalList)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("insertInitialList" + finalList.Count());

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);

            var result = from element in doc.Descendants("Plist")
                         select element;

            foreach (var ele in result)
            {
                ele.Add(from a in finalList
                        select new XElement("EmployeeFinance",
                              new XElement("EmployeeEmploy_Id"),
                              new XElement("EmpPersonal_Id"),
                              new XElement("Employee_Number")));
                doc.Save(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);
            }



        }
```

Comment: In a shorten version of the code above.. i figured it out..

Comment: So are you saying you fixed your problem, or that you found a shorter example of the problem you are still having?

Comment: i fixed it .. sorry .. if i wasnt clear .. little excited ..lol .. its below

Answer (score 0):

in a shorten version of the problem above .. i figure it out and list the code below. thank you**

```
public void insertInitialList(List<EmployeeEmploy> finalList)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("insertInitialList" + finalList.Count());

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);

            var result = from element in doc.Descendants("Plist")
                         select element;

            foreach (var ele in result)
            {
                ele.Add(from a in finalList
                        select new XElement("EmployeeFinance",
                              new XElement("EmployeeEmploy_Id"),
                              new XElement("EmpPersonal_Id"),
                              new XElement("Employee_Number")));
                doc.Save(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);
            }



        }
```